# Linking to a specific tab from a href link

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink, href

I'm trying to link index.html with a href link to players.html -- > ***Pele*** tab.

Here is my ***index.html*** code:

```
  <a href="players.html#client-panel-2"></a>
```

and my ***players.html***

```
              <ul data-tabs="data-tabs" id="example-tabs" class="tabs">
                <li class="tabs-title is-active" tab-community-amenities="tab-community-amenities"
                    role="presentation">
                  <div class="tabs-link" data="#client-panel-0" role="tab" aria-controls="client-panel-0"
                       aria-selected="false" id="client-panel-0-label">Messi
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li class="tabs-title" tab-apartment-amenities="tab-apartment-amenities" role="presentation">
                  <div class="tabs-link" data="#client-panel-1" role="tab" aria-controls="client-panel-1"
                       aria-selected="false" id="client-panel-1-label">Pele
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li class="tabs-title" tab-pet-policy="tab-pet-policy" role="presentation">
                  <div class="tabs-link" data="#client-panel-2" role="tab" aria-controls="client-panel-2"
                       aria-selected="false" id="client-panel-2-label">Kaka
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li class="tabs-title" tab-parking-details="tab-parking-details" role="presentation">
                  <div class="tabs-link" data="#client-panel-3" role="tab" aria-controls="client-panel-3"
                       aria-selected="false" id="client-panel-3-label">Benzema ;)
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li class="tabs-title" tab-parking-details="tab-parking-details" role="presentation">
                  <div class="tabs-link" data="#client-panel-4" role="tab" aria-controls="client-panel-4"
                       aria-selected="false" id="client-panel-4-label">Berbatov
                  </div>
                </li>
              </ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

make the link contain some sort of url variable

```
<a href="players.html?selected=pele-id></a>
```

use jquery its nice

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

add an id tag to make it easier to find with jquery

```
<div id="pele-id" class="tabs-link" data="#client-panel-2" role="tab" aria-controls="client-panel-2"
                       aria-selected="false" id="client-panel-2-label">
```

get that value in a script tag. then edit attr aria-selected to be (I assume this is what you are attempting to change).

```
<script>
var url = new URL(window.location.href);
var selector = url.searchParams.get("selected");
$("#" + selector).attr("aria-selected", "true")
</script>
```

Assuming changing that attr to "true" will do what you want this should work for all the different

Comment: Hi, I have already id = "id="client-panel-2-label", should I deleted and use id="pele-id"? Also which one is correct <a href="players.html?selected="pele-id"></a> or <a href="players.html?selected=pele-id"></a>

Comment: what ever you want, just make sure all the instances in jquery using $(".id") are of the right id. And use the second one is correct, url parameters don't require quotation marks

Comment: sorry just realised that i was the one that put the quotes in mb